# CSS animations triggered by jquery.addClass won't work after loading page content with ajax.load

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I've searched everywhere and not had any luck.

What I'm trying to do is use CSS3 animation triggered by using jQuery addClass. It works fine on a page that doesn't have content populated with jQuery ajax.load method, but when I use ajax.load the animations don't work, despite the addition of the classes happening.

Code:

```
  $.fn.animateAjaxRequest = function() {

      // Variables
      $contentHolder = '#mainContent';

      // Bind to the click event
      $(this).click(function(e) {

          // Stop the click
          e.preventDefault();

          // Get and set some variables
          $destination = $(this).attr('href');
          $articleBreak = 0;

          // Fade out the old content
          $($contentHolder).fadeOut(600, function() {

              // Show loader

              // Get the new data
              $(this).load($destination+' '+$contentHolder+' > *', function() {

                  // Hide the loader

                  // Hide all the articles
                  $('article.whiteBox', this).removeClass('allIn').addClass('out');

                  // Fade this back in
                  $(this).fadeIn(600);

                  // Loop the articles and load them in one-by-one
                  $('article.whiteBox', this).each(function() {

                      // Increment the article break
                      $articleBreak += 300;

                      // Fade the article in
                      $(this).delay($articleBreak).queue(function(next){

                        $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('allIn');
                        next();
                      });

                  });
              });
          });

      });
```

Css:

```css
article.whiteBox {
    &.out {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    &.allOut {
      animation: whiteBoxAllOutAnime 1s;
      -webkit-animation: whiteBoxAllOutAnime 1s;

      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    &.allIn {
      animation: whiteBoxAllInAnime 1.5s;
      -webkit-animation: whiteBoxAllInAnime 1.5s;

      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is would be received gratefully. Like I say when not using ajax.load its fine and the CSS3 animations work ok, but with, it plain doesn't work! Thanks in advance

Comment: Dynamic elements and delegated event handlers, as usual. Are you sure the classes are being added, have you observed the elements in a DOM inspector.

Comment: That looks like LESS or SCSS to me. Just sayin'...

Comment: Could you please provide compiled CSS.

Comment: Checked the inspector, the classes are definitely being added, when tested, the end goal of the transition is achieved, its just not animated...

Comment: That's a funny one :s

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your responses, I've sorted it, there was a duplicate line in one of the mixins, thanks for taking the time to respond though.